# Passing brace-enclosed initializer list with multiple types to function

Tags: c++, templates

How can a brace-enclosed initializer list with multiple types be passed to a function?

I am trying to make the following code work:

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename... types>
void g(std::tuple<types...> args) {}

int main() {
  g({1, 'a', 0.4});                     // does not work
  g<int, char, double>({1, 'a', 0.4});  // works
  g(std::tuple{1, 'a', 0.4});           // works
}
```

I want the line `g({1, 'a', 0.4});` to work without editing it. The compiler (g++ 11.3.0) says that it can not convert `<brace-enclosed initializer list>` to `std::tuple<>`.

This is already surprising because I expected it to deduce the type `std::tuple<int, char, double>`. Further research has shown that the compiler is able to deduce the type of a std::initializer_list correctly in the following:

```
#include <initializer_list>

template <typename type>
void f(std::initializer_list<type> arg) {}

int main() {
  f({1, 2, 3});                       // works
  f<int>({1, 2, 3});                  // works
  f(std::initializer_list{1, 2, 3});  // works
}
```

This is very close to the actual goal but it only works if the types of the objects in the list are the same. My first approach was to look at the implementation of std::initializer_list and implement it myself but I do not even seem to get the `f({1, 2, 3});` line working using my own implementation of initializer_list. Only `f<int>({1, 2, 3});` works with my initializer_list. So the questions are:

- is it possible to implement your own init_list so `f({1, 2, 3});` works when f takes a custom init_list as argument?
- is it possible to extend the implementation to a custom tuple_init_list type so you can make `g({1, 'a', 0.4});` work?
- or is there simply another type that I can pass to g instead of a std::tuple to make it work?

Comment: There is no a constructor [`std::tuple::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple) that takes an initializer list, thus it does not compile.
The second and the last one is same as the constructor initialization `std::tuple(1, 'a', 0.4)`, the second one is the copy initializtion.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a helper function template after the existing one:

```
template <typename... types>
void g(types&& ... args) { g (std::forward_as_tuple (args...)); }
```

With that in place, all three lines compile (C++17 or later), although you do have to change that first line to:

```
g(1, 'a', 0.4);
```

(thanks for pointing that out, apple).

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/293nBnaaww7XNusS)

Note also that `std::initializer_list` can only hold elements of a single type and it is not possible to roll your own (because the name `std::initializer_list` means something to the compiler).

Comment: you changed a line, `f({1, 2, 3});` would not compile

Comment: I guess OP is expecting CTAD to works here. so "`std::initializer_list` can only hold elements of a single type" may not explain much

Comment: @apple Not sure quite _what_ he is expecting, tbh

Comment: yes, just my guess.

Comment: I am expecting g({1, 'a', 0.4}); to deduce the type std::tuple<int,char,double> just like f({1, 2, 3}); deduces the type std::initializer_list<int>. And "I want the line g({1, 'a', 0.4}); to work without editing it."

Comment: @Taranor it is impossible because {1, 'a', 0.4} it is not a type on its own and there's no good candidate to deduce from.

Comment: @Taranor `f({1, 2, 3});` doesn't deduce anything.  `{1, 2, 3}` _is_ an `initializer_list`, and an `initializer_list` can only hold a single type.  Anyway, why are you so attached to those braces?

Comment: My understanding: it works for `std::initializer_list` because it's a kind of built-in type and there is no such type for lists with different types.

Comment: @Taranor Pretty much.  The idea behind `std::initializer_list` is it is extremely lightweight and your hypothetical, heterogeneous type would not be.  (It would be, in essence, a `tuple`!)

Comment: Very unfortunate giving the fact that the compiler is in fact able to deduce the type `std::tuple<int, char, double>` from the line `std::tuple x{1,'a',0.4};`.

Comment: it's because uniform initialization calls a generic constructor where arguments can be easily deduced - it's similar to the solution posted by @PaulSanders. And so from now on you got fully specialized type std::tuple<int, char, double> and candidate std::tuple<Args...> in the template function, so it's also easy to deduce. {1, 'a', 0.4} is no longer initialization_list, it's uniform initialization but the compiler won't know what you want to initialize. It's also not a type on its own hence impossible to deduce